# Switching gcloud accounts for Terraform and Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, gcloud

I have two emails associated with two separate gcloud projects.

I can easily switch the projects with:

```
$ gcloud auth list
  Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
        first@project1
*       second@project2

$ gcloud config set account first@project1
```

I can then see, that gcloud did change the active account. I can also do this with:

```
$ gcloud config configurations list
...
$ gcloud config configurations set project1
```

And I can see the active configuration changes.

However it does not seem to have any effect for `kubectl` and `terraform` commands as they still use the previous configuration.

What am i doing wrong? How should I switch between the projects? It seems it has something to do with `application-default` account, but that looks it cannot be easily switched without relogin?

**Edit**: to precise the question:

What would be a correct sequence of commands to switch between gcloud auths (eg. first@project1, second@project2) so that it is usable in Kubernetes, Terraform and others?

Answer (score 1):

Kubectl and terraform have own config or we can say context

for kubectl you need to change the cluster config using

```
kubectl config get-contexts

kubectl config use-context <cluster-name>
```

Or else each time you have set the context of Kubernetes cluster using Gcloud and it will get auto changed for kubectl

`gcloud container clusters get-credentials cluster-name` which takes the --project also.

Read more at : https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-access-for-kubectl

For changing project in terraform there are different ways

- Using different serviceaccount keys JSON
- Changing project config inside terraform provider
- Setting up environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`

setting project inside the Provider

```
provider "google" {
  project     = "my-project-id"
  region      = "us-central1"
  zone        = "us-central1-c"
}
```

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_reference

Best approach to use : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_reference#credentials-1

As you are writing IAC so all config in code.

List of all possible methods for **authentication** terraform:

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_reference#authentication

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, however - this doesn't seem to be an easy solution to switch between contexts. What would be a sequence of commands to perform if I want to switch between accouns `first@project1` and `second@project2`?

Comment: if you are using service account file only two command there : GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS set variables in OS env with path of specific service account file

Comment: I don!t set this variable, i only use `gcloud` command.

Comment: you can run command for cluster context and latest context will get auto set of kubectl.

Answer (score 1):

SDK provides the following command, this helps in applying credentials to all API calls that make use of the Application Default Credentials client library.

[Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_reference#running-terraform-on-your-workstation) is one of the classic applications that have this dependency.

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

Here is the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login) for the above command.

Comment: This effectively relogins and one must put the login & password - is there a way to switch between logged in accounts like with `gcloud config set account`